How can i solve the PNPM permission error?
Whenever I try to use pnpm to run pnpm install or pnpm add, I always encounter this error, and I have to add the sudo command for install or add to execute properly. Where and how should I set permissions to run without the sudo command?

I updated pnpm initially and later proceeded with uninstalling and reinstalling it. However, the issue remained unresolved.
